# Auto Mapper v4.2.1 - Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have an asp.net mvc application developed with VS2015.

In the Application_Start method of Global.asax.cs a method containing the following is called:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Domain.ESB.Fault, Models.FaultVmRec>());
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Models.FaultVmRec, Domain.ESB.Fault>());
```

I've checked that this does get executed by adding a breakpoint.

In my controller, I have the following:

```
faultVmRec = Mapper.Map<Fault, FaultVmRec>(item);
```

At this line, I'm getting the exception:

> {"Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nFault -> FaultVmRec\r\nLGSS.Unit4.BamPortal.Domain.ESB.Fault -> LGSS.Unit4.BamPortal.Website.Models.FaultVmRec\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nFaultVmRec\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nSystem.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Fault_805BF7128A26886D33A8989DFA212C8E378EDADE588B0922B23ECFE7F697D907"}

However, if I paste in to explicitly initialize the mapping before executing the map as follows:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Domain.ESB.Fault, Models.FaultVmRec>());
faultVmRec = Mapper.Map<Fault, FaultVmRec>(item);
```

Then it works fine!

Anyone see where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: Why would you not just do something like `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<>(); cfg.CreateMap<>();` but further more, why don't you use profiles instead. This has become the standard way with automapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Domain.ESB.Fault, Models.FaultVmRec>));  Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Models.FaultVmRec, Domain.ESB.Fault>());`

This code snippet overrides each other. You should configure as:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<Domain.ESB.Fault, Models.FaultVmRec>();
  cfg.CreateMap<Models.FaultVmRec, Domain.ESB.Fault>();
  cfg.
  cfg... //so on

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Calls to `Initialize` instantiate a new configuration. Combine them like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { 
  cfg.CreateMap<Domain.ESB.Fault, Models.FaultVmRec>();
  cfg.CreateMap<Models.FaultVmRec, Domain.ESB.Fault>();
});
```

Also you should validate your configuration after you Initialize to catch potential runtime errors [documented here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation):

```
Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```